# GA doesn't receive data from Tumblr when everything is correct

Tags: google-analytics, tumblr

Recently I changed my Tumblr theme, and there is no Google Analytics data received. I've checked and make sure that the Google Analytics ID is correctly put in, as guided in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHuS8uXsYE0). There should be no accidentally incorrect filter, because I haven't changed it. Using [GA Checker](http://www.gachecker.com/) and it says "Error occured while crawling site." Open the viewsource of [the site](https://quacau.tumblr.com/?utm_source=Stack%20Exchange&utm_medium=Webmasters&utm_campaign=Help)<sup>*</sup> and there is a ga code as expected:

```
<script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
              ga('create', 'UA-67467499-3', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
            </script>
```

Do you know what's wrong?

<sup>* The link has tracking tail so if it works, it will show data too. I hope this is fine.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correctly setup. One just need to wait for some times to for new visitors.